# MongoDB, how to create an empty collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

How can I create an empty collection in MongoDB?

I've tried various things but they didn't work, that would be declaring it differently. What I know is that it should create a collection automatically when needed, but not sure.

However, you could technically create a collection and delete that what is inside.

This is an example on what I've tried:

```
function test() {
        db.createCollection("test", function() {});
        console.log("Collection has been created.")
};
test();
```

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"?

Comment: How does it "not work"? What other ways did you try? How are you testing that it has been created? Please elaborate.

Comment: Why do you want to create an empty collection?

Comment: @Mani I need it to check if a collection exist and if it doesn't it creates it, so I can use the updateOne function and enter like people that type in the command into the database.

Comment: I have to create the collection first before I can search through it otherwise it results an error and I need to search through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB no need to explicitly check if a collection already exists or not before doing any CRUD operations.

MongoDB will create the collections on the when it is required.

Comment: When I attempt to do updateOne, it doesn't, together with upsert option. :/ But for the other I think it did I think I'm just using something wrong

Comment: I have to create the collection first before I can search through it otherwise it results an error and I need to search through it

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a collection for me and prints your log message:

```
function test() {
        db.createCollection("test");
        console.log("Collection has been created.")
};
test();
```

I removed the function(){} in your db.createCollection, maybe that caused your error?

Comment: After searching someone actually added the function() {} to make it work

Comment: I don't get any error at all, when I refresh the collection isn't there.